# How do I make a javascript program that checks if the array values are consecutive in reverse?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was making a JavaScript program that would check if array contains consecutive values like 1,2,3,4,5 or 5,4,3,2,1. Now, I've been successful in checking if it contains numbers in order like 1,2,3,4,5 but for some reason I just can't seem to make it work for checking in reverse order (like 5,4,3,2,1)

Here's my code:

```
let nums = prompt("Enter number separated by hyphen");
let numcol = nums.split("-");
let intnumcol = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numcol.length; i++) {
  intnumcol.push(parseInt(numcol[i]));
}
for (let j = 0; j < intnumcol.length; j++) {
  if (j > 0) {
    if (intnumcol[j] === ++intnumcol[j - 1] || intnumcol[j]===--intnumcol[j-1]  )  {
      let flag = true;

      if (!flag)
        break;

      if (j == intnumcol.length - 1 && flag == true) {
        console.log("consecutive");
        break;
      }
    } else {
      console.log("not consecutive")
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Here, in this statement:

```
if (intnumcol[j] === ++intnumcol[j - 1] || intnumcol[j]===--intnumcol[j-1]  )
```

I do have the OR condition for checking reversed order values but for some reason, it is not working. I don't know why. So please help me.

Here's the JS Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/Lrwagc3m/

Also, please don't confuse this to be the duplicate of some other question because my questions asks for why this certain code doesn't work for checking reverse order consecutive values and for knowing the code to make it work.

Comment: Check if it's sequential ascending, then check again on `numcol.revverse()`.

Comment: Do you want to handle just 1234554321(palindroms) or 543535430001234554321000543543 as well?

Comment: you mean if it does work for values like 1,2,3,4,5? Because it does as I have specified in the question. I'll check for reverse

Comment: @Silviu Burcea I just need to check for consecutive values (assuming user doesn't enter duplicates)

Comment: How would `if (!flag)` _ever_ be true here, if you are doing `let flag = true;` right before that, and aren’t changing the value of `flag` _anywhere_ else …?

Comment: @Heretic Monkey it does work for numcol.reverse() but now I can't check for values in order like 1,2,3,4,5.. now it only checks for values like 5,4,3,2,1

Comment: @CBroe the flag is for just checking if the condition is satisfied, if it is then i put true in flag. if even one iteration doesn't return true, I want to break the loop so for this purpose I have used if (!flag)

Comment: But you are only ever _checking_ for the value of that flag, right after you have _set_ it to true. There is no case ever here, where flag _could_ be false at that point where you are checking it.

Comment: Use a function to encapsulate the process of checking. Take the array as an argument. Then you can run the function twice; once with `numcol`, once with `numcol.reverse()`. It will always fail one of those runs -- that's on purpose. All you care about is that it passes at least one of the runs, right?

Comment: The reason I set the flag was, again to check if all the values are consecutive.. without the flag if I'd enter 3,5,6. It would give me consecutive because 5,6 are consecutive. With flag, it gives me consecutive if every value if consecutive

Comment: @Heretic Monkey yes it's working now. Thanks

Comment: hi @ohnope I apologize for writing an answer so late, does this help you, is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I have put together some functions to help you determine if an array contains only numbers in ascending or descending order. The most important is the `consecutiveChecker` which receives the array and a function that compares 2 consecutive elements. If there are any 2 consecutive elements which don't respect this condition, the function will return false. If we reached the end of array, it will return true.

As you can see, I have 2 filters prepared, one that checks ascending order and another one for checking descending order, which are later used in `consecutiveAscOrDescChecker`, for which I've written some test cases and some code similar to yours to prompt the user for some numbers and return back the answer.

```js
const ascendingOrder = (a, b) => a - b === -1;
const descendingOrder = (a, b) => ascendingOrder(b, a);

const consecutiveChecker = (array, consecutiveFilter) => {
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (!consecutiveFilter(array[i - 1], array[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

const consecutiveAscOrDescChecker = (array) =>
    consecutiveChecker(array, ascendingOrder) ||
    consecutiveChecker(array, descendingOrder);

const testCases = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],    // true
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],    // false
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],    // true
    [-1, 0, 1],         // true
    [1, 0, -1],         // true
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4],    // false
    [1],                // true
    []                  // true
];

for (const array of testCases) {
    console.log(array, consecutiveAscOrDescChecker(array));
}

const numbers = prompt("Enter numbers separed by '-'")
    .split("-")
    .map(x => parseInt(x));
alert(`${numbers} array is ${consecutiveAscOrDescChecker(numbers) ? 'consecutive' : 'not consecutive'}`);
```

Note: this setup let's you check other things easily, e.g. what if you wanted to check if consecutive elements grow by 2? Easy:

```js
const growByTwo = consecutiveChecker(array, (a, b) => a - b === -2);
```

Wanna check if an array elements grows/shrinks by a particular number? Easy:

```js
const consecutiveBy = (x) => {
    const ascendingByX = (a, b) => a - b === -x;
    const descendingByX = (a, b) => ascendingByX(b, a);
    return (array) =>
        consecutiveChecker(array, ascendingByX) ||
        consecutiveChecker(array, descendingByX);
}

const consecutiveByThree = consecutiveBy(3);
console.log(consecutiveByThree([1, 3, 5])); // false
console.log(consecutiveByThree([1, 4, 7])); // true
```

With this function, `consecutiveAscOrDescChecker` would be as easy as:

```js
const consecutiveAscOrDescChecker = consecutiveBy(1);
console.log(consecutiveAscOrDescChecker([1, 2, 4])); // false
console.log(consecutiveAscOrDescChecker([1, 2, 3])); // true
```

Note that you can't use `Math.abs` with `consecutiveChecker` as it would give you a different outcome, e.g.
`consecutiveChecker([1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0], (a, b) => Math.abs(a - b) === 1);` would return true(!!) because the difference between any 2 consecutive elements, ascending or descending, is 1, which is a different problem than yours.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like the below which will help you to find out whatever input was provided in ascending or descending order

```
AscendingOrDescending = (inputString) =>  {
    const arrayOfNumbers= Array.from(inputString);
  const asscendingResult = arrayOfNumbers.every((number,index,array) => { 
                return index < array.length ? Number(number) + 1 === Number(array[index+1]) || Number(number) - 1 === Number(array[index-1]) : true;
        });
  return asscendingResult ? 'string is in ascending or descending order' : 'string is not in ascending or descending order'      
}
console.log(AscendingOrDescending("123456"))
```